# Place three separate arrays into shared memory

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a parallel programming assignment using multiprocessing and multithreading (implementing a parallel solution to find the [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of two strings, by antidiagonal wave propagation). I have three separate arrays (actually `int*`s) representing the first, middle and last antidiagonal of the 'wave', all stored in a struct, like such:

```
typedef struct shared_buffer
{
    int *back;
    int *middle;
    int *front;
} shared_buff;
```

In `main()`, I have the following declarations:

```
// MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH is a macro, defined as the *minimum* of the lengths of the two input strings

int id = shmget(ftok("/dev/null", 5), MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH * 3, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
shared_buff* shared_mem = (shared_buff *) shmat(id, nullptr, 0);

shared_mem->back   = std::memcpy((int*)calloc(MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH, sizeof(int)));
shared_mem->middle = std::memcpy((int*)calloc(MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH, sizeof(int)));
shared_mem->front  = std::memcpy((int*)calloc(MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH, sizeof(int)));
```

However, from what I have learnt, apparently shared memory does *not* like storing pointers, and this breaks after `fork()`ing. Writing to the arrays in the child processes, and printing said arrays in the parent process, does *not* return the expected values.

Hence, my question: how can I store these three arrays in shared memory, so that the entire process family may easily access said arrays with square brackets `[]`?

Comment: Why the `typedef`?

Comment: No real reason, merely for convenience.

Comment: What kind of *convenience*? This is not C. You can just do `struct name` and refer to it by `name`. Zero needs for `typedef`. I suggest abandoning any C++ source that introduced such practice to you.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. As for abandoning source, I had no such thing; in fact, I've been learning C++ rather hastily, as my post history might suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You are sharing the `int`s, not the `int *`s. Each process needs it's own `shared_buff`.

```
int id = shmget(ftok("/dev/null", 5), MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH * 3, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
int* shared = reinterpret_cast<int *>(shmat(id, nullptr, 0));

shared_buff shared_mem;
shared_mem.back = shared;
shared_mem.middle = shared + MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH;
shared_mem.front = shared + (2 * MAX_ANTIDIAG_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I'd like to swap the arrays around, would this work with a strightforward `std::swap`?

Comment: @SRSR333 what do you mean "swap the arrays around"? the `int`s or the `int *`s?